# Unable to bind a dropdownlist to list dictionary collection

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, formview

I am unable to bind a dropdownlist to list dictionary collection(in code behind) at runtime. Dropdownlist is inside a formview's insertitemtemplate. Please provide solutions.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried first.

Comment: please let us see your code and what way are you trying?

Answer (score 0):

In FormView's `DataBound` event handler:

```
protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    switch (FormView1.CurrentMode){
        case FormViewMode.ReadOnly:
            break;
        case FormViewMode.Edit:
            break;
        case FormViewMode.Insert:
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("DdlID");
            var dict = new Dictionary<String,String>();
            dict.Add("1", "Foo");
            ddl.DataSource = dict;
            ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
            ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
            ddl.DataBind();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AnkushJain the rule is you mark the answer as accepted/answered if it satisfies you, so that other users with the same problem will benefit from it. And upvoting means : `The answer is useful` nothing more ! you can find these buttons on the top left corner of the answer

Comment: @nuux - thank you nuux but i can't vote until i get 15 reoutation and second thing i am not getting where is option for accepted/ marked ?